# Locate data from parameter-string in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, syntax

I have a big csv-file (maybe ~2000 entries) containing a list of files (column 0) that are described by several parameters (rest of the columns) looking like this (the first column is just for readability, it's not explicitly contained in the csv-file):

```
(i) Filename; File extension; Month created; Year created; Author; Notes;
0   file1; txt; 07; 2015; AB; NaN;
1   file2; txt; 07; 2015; AB; NaN;
2   file2b; txt; 07; 2015; AB; some notes;
3   file3; txt; 06; 2013; CD; some text;
4   file4; txt; 06; 2012; EF; other text;
5   file5; txt; 05; 2011; EF; NaN;
...
```

I've read in the whole file with pandas.read_csv() into a data frame (called `files_df`). What I'd like to do now is to retrieve all files that match certain critera. E.g. get all files that were created in July, 2015 by Author AB and that does not have any notes should find matches line 0 + 1, but not in all the others.

I can already retrieve files with

```
files_df.loc[(files_df['Month created'] == '07') &
             (files_df['Year created'] == '2015') &
             (files_df['Author'] == 'AB') &
             (files_df['Notes'].isnull())]
```

But how can I fill in the Strings automaticall in python? I have stored a bunch of combinations for filtering in `dictionary`-type variables with key and values. But I can't think of a way to fill in the Strings automatically.
Can anybody point me in the right direction?

(I haven't worked much with Python, dictionaries was just the first type to come to mind, I don't have to use them if a different type was better suited for this.)

[Edit for clarification:]

A typical input looks like this:

```
parameters = {'Month created': {'07'},
              'Year created': {'2015'},
              'Author': {'AB'},
              'Notes': {}}
```

What I'd like to do is, write something like this:

```
def read_files(parameters):
    files = files_df.loc[
           # how to fill parameter keys & values here???
           ]
    return files
```

Comment: What do you want to 'fill in' and with what do you want to fill them?

Comment: Thanks for asking, it seems my question was unclearly written. I've edited the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying around for a while, I found this solution. It looks like an unpretty hack, but well...

```
def read_files(files_df, parameters):
    idx = []
    for key in parameters.keys():
        if len(idx) == 0:
            idx = (files_df[key] == parameters[key])
        else:
            idx = idx & (files_df[key] == parameters[key])
    idx = idx & files_df['Notes'].isnull()
    files = files_df.loc[idx]

    return files
```